# Keep getting stack smashing error

Tags: c

I have an buffer of size 101

```
 char buffer[101]
```

I am trying to copy an address to the array

```
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i+=4)
     *(long*)&buffer[i] = address
```

in which address is of type long.

However I met with a stack smashing detection when I am running it. Any idea why?

Comment: Because your `buffer` is not evenly divisible by `sizeof long` and the last access runs out of bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alignment issues aside,

```
 for(i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i+=4)
     *(long*)&buffer[i] = address
```

when `i == 100` you write past the allocated buffer. You should stop when `i > sizeof buffer - 4`.